# Data race in MFC in afxCurrentResourceHandle

Tags: multithreading, mfc

we have an issue in MFC-based application related to “current MFC state” and threads. In main thread we call VisualManager, because we want to have fancy toolbars. The call ends up in `CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::OnUpdateSystemColors` function located inside `afxvisualmanageroffice2007.cpp`, which changes “current resource handle” by calling `AfxSetResourceHandle` function. This function gets “current module state” and changes “current resource handle” from `MyApp.exe` to `mfc140u.dll`. This is fine, because assets for VisualManager are located in that DLL and the change will be restored back to `MyApp.exe` in all cases.

However, what is not fine is that we spawn a new thread just before call to VisualManager (by using `AfxBeginThread`), this thread needs to load some strings from string table (by using `CString` class), but it sometimes fails to do so. It fails because there is race with main thread about `AFX_MODULE_STATE::m_hCurrentResourceHandle` variable. The thread expect it to be set to `MyApp.exe`, but the main thread changes it to `mfc140u.dll` and back, the “current resource handle” is effectively a global variable.

So, my questions are: 1) Are we doing something obviously wrong managing our MFC-based threads? Should we somehow copy or protect the “module state” so our new thread is immune to the change main thread is doing? Should aim MFC to create something like per-thread variable / state? 2) I believe Microsoft is wrong here, changing what is effectively a global variable and screwing other threads expectations, VisualManager should obtain the handle and pass it to all its functions as a parameter. Am I right?

EDIT:

Hi guys @iinspectable, @cha, I have an update, sorry it took so long. Steps to reproduce: Open Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, Create new MFC application through the wizard, make sure it has the "Project style" and "Visual style and colors" selected as "Office" and "Office 2007 (Blue theme)". Open file `afxvisualmanageroffice2007.cpp` from MSVS folder and put 4 break-points into `CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::OnUpdateSystemColors` function where it calls `AfxSetResourceHandle`. Open file `MFCApplication1.cpp` in your newly created project folder and put this code [1] into `CMFCApplication4App::InitInstance` function just before `CMainFrame* pMainFrame = new CMainFrame;`, put break-point into this thread proc.

Now build and run this MFC application in debug mode, on each break-point hit, use freeze thread and thaw thread functions from Threads window, so you will arrange main thread in the middle of `CMFCVisualManagerOffice2007::OnUpdateSystemColors` function just after setting the global variable using `AfxSetResourceHandle` function and the worker thread before `CStringT::LoadString`. Now the load string will fail because it is looking for it inside `mfc140ud.dll` instead of using resource chain and `MFCApplication1.exe`.

I believe this is Microsoft's bug (changing global variable for a while), my code-base is full of innocent `CString::LoadString` calls which rely on carefully and correctly constructed resource chain with various plug-in DLLs and with an .exe at the end. If this is not Microsoft's bug then it is my bug relying on MFC on providing me a usable resource chain. I would need to create my own resource-chain-like functionality and use it everywhere when loading strings and other stuff from resources.

```
// [1]
AFX_THREADPROC thread_proc = [](LPVOID pParam){
    CString str;
    str.LoadString(IDS_CAPTION_TEXT);
    UINT ret = 0;
    return ret;
};
::AfxBeginThread(thread_proc, (LPVOID)nullptr);
// Same result with ::AfxBeginThread(CRuntimeClass*) overload.
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong, somehow. The "current" (or "active") module state is managed per thread. See [Managing the State Data of MFC Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0asx94f7.aspx) as well as [TN058: MFC Module State Implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft1t4bbc.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable These two articles discuss module states, I believe I don't need to handle module states, I need to change per-thread module state pointer to something meaningful or disallow this change in main thread. The main thread's module state points to global module state and the other thread's module state is NULL, so it uses the global module state, which is now switched / corrupted for a while.

Comment: Well, yes, if you break module state management, there's nothing the framework can do to fix that for you. The solution is to not break module state management. Part of the solution is to make sure that your threads are `CWinThread`-derived.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh no, I believe I didn't break the state management, I just launched new thread by calling `AfxBeginThread` which creates `CWinThread` which I believe is correct way of creating MFC-managed threads. And this new thread sees ground moving underneath it, which is unfortunate and I want to prevent it some way or another. BTW this is reproducible even with only one "module" `MyApp.exe`, I don't explicitly change the module anywhere.

Comment: use [CStringT::LoadString(HINSTANCE hInstance, UINT nID);](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a44fb3wy.aspx) to load the string from your App resource. Do not use `LoadString(UINT nID);`

Comment: Hi @cha, I need to take advantage of the MFC resource chain too. So your idea is fine for this particular case, but I would need to re-implement the resource chain functionality to protect myself from other threads changing global state.

Comment: I'm going off on a limb, but [AfxBeginThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx) has two overloads: The first one is meant to be used with *"worker threads"*, the second for *"UI threads"*. I haven't checked this, but maybe you need a UI thread to manage module state per thread. I know that I have used `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` successfully in a multithreaded environment, so something must be different with your code. If you can, try to provide a [mcve].